.gitignore ignore any subfolder with name .vscode
I'm starting a repo with 1 development project and 1 testing project, so there are 2 different projects in the same repo, I'm working with Visual Studio Code.
I need to specify in the .gitignore file that any .vscode subfolder in the local repo shouldn't be uplodaded when I make a commit.
Here is the main part of my .gitignore file
### VisualStudioCode ###
.vscode/*
**/.vscode/*
**/.vscode

But it's not working, when I prepare a commit it keeps recognizing all .vscode subfolders as you can see on this Git Extensions screenshot

Any idea?
EDIT:
The problem was I had uploaded a .gitignore.txt file instead of .gitignore file, since my business laptop had hidden file extensions! Thanks anyway dudes :S

Have you tried a single .vscode yet? No slashes and asterisks. In my test that works perfectly fine.

Do those green pluses indicate an "add" which suggests those files are not tracked yet?

@Boldewyn tried with a single .vscode in the top of the .gitignore and the result is the same, it detects and upload all .vscode subfolders and files :(

I'm voting to close this question due to a typo in the .gitignore filename.

I tried to delete it, but couldn't

It is enough to enter .vscode/.
But if you already commited it, you have to untrack it by:
git rm --cached .vscode
git commit -m "Untracked '.vscode' folder."


I have only commited the .gitignore file with all suggestions made in the answers. When I try to make a new commit with the project files it detects and upload all .vscode subfolders and files (+20Mb)

You should inspect your remote repo in order to be sure that you did not really committed ,vscode in the past.

This is a good answer for the scenario where the files are already committed. The picture kind of looks like the files are being added rather than modified though. (Turns out OP had a typo in his .gitignore file name.)
